# Swap Characters Using Command Prompt

Tags: java, file, command-line

Trying to write a program called `SwapChars.java` using command line arguments that allows any two characters to be swapped. For example if the program was called `SwapChars` then to swap all ‘a’s and ‘b’s in a file `test.txt` we would type

```
java SwapChars test.txt ab
```

I typed the following code which kept giving me an exception error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SwapChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String a = args[0]; //file name (test.txt entered into command line)
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(a);
        String b = args[1];//which characters to swap
        int t = fr.read();
        while(t!=-1)
        {
            if(t==b.charAt(0))
            {
                System.out.println(b.charAt(1));
            }
            else if(t==b.charAt(1))
            {
                System.out.println(b.charAt(0));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println((char)t);
            }
                    t=fr.read();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Exception error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at SwapChars.main(SwapChars.java:7)
```

I can get the desired output when I change my code to remove the need for commands as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SwapCharsTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
    String swap = "ab";
    int t = fr.read();
    while(t!=-1)
    {
        if(t==swap.charAt(0))
        {
            System.out.print(swap.charAt(1));
        }
        else if(t==swap.charAt(1))
        {
            System.out.print(swap.charAt(0));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print((char)t);
        }
        t=fr.read();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: _"...kept giving me an exception..."_ - Is there a reason you omitted the exception from your question? Please [edit] your post and add the complete stack trace, including all Caused By sections (if any), and identify the statement in your code that threw the exception.

Comment: DO NOT FORMAT STACK TRACES WITH BLOCK QUOTES -- USE CODE FORMATTING

Comment: What do you think `java.io.FileNotFoundException` means?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm assuming it means that it cannot trace the file I entered into the command line, i.e. test.txt. However, it is a valid file and when I change this program such that it doesn't receive commands, the program works with no problem

Comment: Sorry, _"change this program such that it doesn't receive commands"_ doesn't make sense.  @Stefan's answer is correct, and also points out two more problems in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because the file cannot be found. Try to refer to the file with a full path.

Also, when the file is found, your program will loop forever. And the printout can easily be improved. Make these two changes:

```
        else
        {
            System.out.println((char) t);                      
        }
        t = fr.read();
    }
```

(`t = fr.read();` reads a new char for every loop, `(char)` casts the integer so it looks better on screen)

If you don't want to use a full path, you need to figure out where Java will look for the file. This will (most likely) show you where to put the file:

```
System.out.println(new File("dummy").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Sure test.txt is valid. But you must then know where to put the test.txt file. Obviously it is currently in the wrong folder. I've updated my answer; hopefully that will help you to figure out where to put test.txt.